# how to update a record from the values taken from the text box fields

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am making a list of records in a web form with edit and delete options.  I have retrieved the values in the text box fields for update. Now, when
the user clicks the update button, the record is updated.

How can I do it remaining on the same page or redirected to another page?

This is my code:

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
       binddata();
    }
 }
   SqlConnection con;
   SqlDataAdapter da;
   DataSet ds;

  void   binddata()
  {
   string pid = Request.QueryString["Prod_Id"];
   con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\sqlexpress; initial catalog=PracticeDb; user id=sa; pwd=manager;");
    con.Open();
    da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from Products where Prod_Id='" + pid + "'", con);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    con.Close();

   string  P_Name = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Prod_Name"].ToString();
   string U_Prce = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Unit_Price"].ToString();
   string I_Hnd = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["In_Hand"].ToString();
   string Fxd = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Fixed"].ToString();
   string Stus = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Status"].ToString();

   TextBox1.Text = P_Name;
   TextBox2.Text = U_Prce;
   TextBox3.Text = I_Hnd;
   TextBox4.Text = Fxd;
   TextBox5.Text = Stus;
 }

 protected void Unnamed1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {                  
   string pid = Request.QueryString["Prod_Id"];
   var Pd_nme = TextBox1.Text;
   decimal Uni_prce = decimal.Parse(TextBox2.Text);
   int In_hnd = int.Parse(TextBox3.Text);
   string Fxd = TextBox4.Text;
   string Stus = TextBox5.Text;
   SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
   con.ConnectionString = ("Data Source=.\\sqlexpress; initial catalog=PracticeDb; user id=sa; pwd=manager;");
    con.Open();
    string qry = "UPDATE PRODUCTS SET Prod_Name='" + Pd_nme + "',Unit_Price='" + Uni_prce + "',In_Hand='" + In_hnd + "',Fixed='" + Fxd + "',Status='" + Stus + "' where Prod_Id='" + pid + "'";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, con);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();                   
 }
}
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the edit .any solutions ?

Comment: there are multiple solutions for doing such a thing...
1. For staying on the same page, you can use javascript+ajax to post the updated values.
2. For redirection you can create a query string and add parameters to it and update it on other page...

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Your code for updating the database looks okay from here. Do you get any errors?

Comment: Alexander no its not updating the database and there are no error .when i insert the values in the textbox on button click they reappear unchanged

Comment: @HmxaMughal yup the query works in sql server .

Comment: well the only problem i can think of is that you are doing an update on a postback and trying to access a querystring from it, which i dont know how you are setting it, or are you even setting it or not....make a hidden field and store a product_id in that field, when you want to update it, access it from that field....

Comment: @user2431114: 1st of all heres bad textbox naming convention, Inviting `SQL Injection`,  For list of record to be Add/Edit/Delete you can use `Asp.Net GridView` Control

Comment: @HmxaMughal how can do it with the hiddenfield? i mean how can i save the record key value

Comment: Is Unnamed1_Click called at all?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access the query string on a postback, which does not make any sense...now you have multiple options to achieve what you are trying to do here...i will try to list one or two of them....

**Hidden Field:**
Create a hidden field in the page using:

`<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdn_field" />`

and in your page_load set its value to a `Prod_Id` from a `QueryString`...and now you can access it in your postbacks by just `hdnField.Value`..

**ViewState:**
You can save the value in a ViewState and use it in your postbacks....

**AJAX:**
Create an ajax call to a same or different page and send the object to the server by serializing it to JSON/XML and then handle the update from that page

Comment: Why does it not make sense? The QueryString is totally available on PostBack.

Comment: Yes it is available, i know that, you can change it in the client side prior to submitting the form, but it does not make sense is because it is not recommended, at least by me, because...it will change the URL on every postback...and why go through this hassle when you can achieve the same with other ways...

Comment: The QueryString does not manipulate the URL on a PostBack. Did I misunderstand?

Comment: ohhhh i think you misunderstood what is meant to say in the answer, yes the QueryString is definitely available in the postback but if it is a normal postback (by which i mean the URL is not manipulated ), then there will nothing inside the querystring...that is what i meant, i mean you have to manipulate the URL to get something from querystring

Comment: If there was a QueryString in the initial Request, it will be there in a PostBack.